# Derby db connectivity problem on Intelij IDEA about a java project

Tags: java, derby

When I press the test connection button on Intelij IDEA I get this error:

> XJ004][40000] Database 'C:/Program Files/Java/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin' not found.

Can you help me with this?
[image]

Comment: Just out of cutiosity try path without spaces

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevdvlp17453.html) ? Your URL is incorrect. Just out of curiosity, how did you arrive at that URL?

Comment: The URL should be the location of the database that you want to open.

Comment: I am sorry but I am a newbie in databases. Please can you help me to find the correct path of the database?

Comment: Have you created a database already? I'm guessing that you have not. In that case you need to check the _Create database_ check box in the screen capture you posted in your question. The path can be any path you like. The path has nothing to do with where you installed the Derby JAR files. I think you really should read the Derby documentation. Maybe start with [Quick Start](https://db.apache.org/derby/quick_start.html)